# SQL Server native client 10.0 versus OleDb differences?

Tags: sql, performance, linked-server

We have an SQL Server 2008 R1 Environment.

We have poorly performing queries across linked servers which are quite complex.

First question:
Are there any differences between (particularly performance) of SQL native client 10.0 and the listing for oledb within linked servers? My understanding of this was that Native client just packages up oledb with some other items. But I would appreciate some guidance.

Additionally does anyone know where to find some good white papers on optimising Linked server queries?

many thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

If you have poorly performing queries across linked servers, you might want to consider using openquery or some other variations.  Or possibly putting the logic in a stored procedure on the remote server.  This would be much easier if the data do not have to co-mingle with local data.  Sometimes it's faster to send to the remote server a small dataset to "work with" or filter on.

ie. in the past, i've called a sp on the remote server with a list of accountids.  this is much easier now with xml datatypes.

This difference is explained here... [SQL Server linked server performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248753/sql-server-linked-server-performance)